# Stop notification for certain tweet?

Tags: twitter, notifications

Whenever I log into Twitter, I often see notifications for a mildly popular tweet I made a while ago. It's rather annoying to see that someone Retweeted or Liked something I don't care about anymore. While deleting that tweet would resolve this, it would deprive others from reading that tweet onwards. Is there a way to suppress notifications for that particular tweet while receiving those for the rest?

Comment: I need an answer for that too.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any direct way to mute notifications for a single tweet that you've made.

There are two workarounds that might work depending on the tweet in question:

1. If the tweet uses a certain word or hashtag that is uncommon and you don't use anywhere else, you can try adding that word to your muted keywords list: https://twitter.com/settings/muted_keywords
2. You can try muting the tweet as part of a conversation. Click on the tweet to open it as a popup, then click on the little down arrow in the upper-right corner of the tweet. In the menu that appears, click on "Mute this conversation". The downside to this is that if there are any other tweets in the conversation that you *do* want notifications for, you won't get them.